# zscroll text in the tmux status bar

Tags: tmux, zshrc

I am trying to configure my .tmux.conf to display a scrolling string of text.  For what it is worth, the scrolling text is an aviation weather observation that is scraped using a really ugly bash script that is defined in .zshrc as follows:

```
function scrollMetar {
  curl -s "https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kjyo&format=raw&date=&hours=0" | awk '/Data\ starts\ here/{getline; print}' | html2text | zscroll -l 14 -n 0
}
```

I want to take the scrolling output from the `scrollMetar` command and have that scroll on the tmux status line.

My current .tmux.conf section looks like this:

```
set-option -g status-left "\
#[fg=colour7, bg=colour241]#{?client_prefix,#[bg=colour167],} ❐ #S \
#[fg=colour241, bg=colour237] \
#(echo 'TEST TEXT') \
#{?window_zoomed_flag, ,} "
```

Where the `echo 'TEST TEXT'` is should be where the `scrollMetar` would go, but when inserted doesn't output anything.

I am guessing that this maybe a limitation of tmux, but I would be grateful for any advice and I am completely open to alternate implementations.

Comment: Scrolling text in `tmux` is an attention distraction and counter productive for most `tmux` user (I do not use clock for this reason). I suggest make it scroll in response to UI event like hover or click.

Comment: I tend to not use the mouse, so that's not particularly convenient for me, and I tend to need to have this information on hand at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems like .tmux.conf did not like calling the function, or could not find it.  Putting the function in a executable shell script fixed the problem.